# Qt Parsing and comparing the value in qt

Tags: json, api, qt, qml, qtreewidget

I have json format like this->
{
"id": 7,
"sort_decs": "Identity",
"last_name": "Lawson",
},
{
"id": 8,
"sort_decs": "Identity",
"last_name": "Ferguson",
},
{
"id": 9,
"sort_decs": "Identity",
"last_name": "Funke",
},
{
"id": 10,
"sort_decs": "Identity",
"last_name": "Fields",
},
{
"id": 11,
"sort_decs": "Identity",
"last_name": "Edwards",
}

In qtreewidget how can I get sort_desc value for parent1 and last_name in its childs. if the sort_decs value is repeated how can get it only once in parent1 and last_name 's in childs .

I am gettting if the sort_decs value is == "Identity" manually.

Comment: Please try to split up your problem as much as possible: parsing json, filling up a qtreewidget, sorting a qtreewidget, ... Try to solve each problem separately. Ask a specific question about a subproblem if needed. Also try to improve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You may not even need to use `TreeView`. If I understand your data correctly you could use a `ListView` with `section.property: "sort_decs"`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    ListView {
        id: listview
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: [
{ "id": 1, "sort_decs": "Griffindor", "last_name": "Potter", },
{ "id": 2, "sort_decs": "Griffindor", "last_name": "Weasley", },
{ "id": 3, "sort_decs": "Griffindor", "last_name": "Granger", },
{ "id": 4, "sort_decs": "Slytherin",  "last_name": "Malfoy", },
{ "id": 5, "sort_decs": "Slytherin",  "last_name": "Crabbe", },
{ "id": 6, "sort_decs": "Slytherin",  "last_name": "Goyle", },
{ "id": 7, "sort_decs": "Identity", "last_name": "Lawson", },
{ "id": 8, "sort_decs": "Identity", "last_name": "Ferguson", },
{ "id": 9, "sort_decs": "Identity", "last_name": "Funke", },
{ "id": 10, "sort_decs": "Identity", "last_name": "Fields", },
{ "id": 11, "sort_decs": "Identity", "last_name": "Edwards", }
               ]
        delegate: ItemDelegate {
            width: ListView.view.width - 20
            background: Item { }
            text: modelData.last_name
            padding: 0
            icon.source: "Tree.svg"
        }
        section.property: "sort_decs"
        section.criteria: ViewSection.FullString
        section.delegate: ItemDelegate {
            //width: ListView.view.width - 20
            padding: 2
            background: Rectangle { border.color: "#888" }
            text: section; font.pointSize: 14
        }
        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            width: 20
            policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOn
        }
    }
}

// Tree.svg
<svg width="32" height="32">
<path d="M16 0 16 32 M16 16 32 16" stroke="black" fill="none"/>
</svg>
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Hi this works but I am getting this formatted json from api services.How can I get the results like yours